# Django custom command object ID not found

Tags: python, django, django-models

SOLVED:

The try - catch was finding something at a later step in the process

I moved these steps outside of the try - catch and resolved those issues

---

I'm trying to build a custom Django command which can be run against individual model objects

When I check in shell I see the object fine

```
>>> Obj.objects.get(id=1)
<Obj: the object I'm looking for>
```

My custom command however looks like the below:

```
# app/management/update.py
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('--id')

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        if options['id']:
            try:
                obj = Obj.objects.get(id=options['id'])
                # do things
            except:
                raise CommandError('no object with ID: "%s"' % options['id'])
        else:
            # do other things
```

Running this I get the error message

```
>>> python manage.py update --id 1
CommandError: no object with ID: "1"
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: In example your have `ID=1` but in command `ID=2`?

Comment: Log the exact Exception. With your bare `except` (never do that!), you obscure what actually happens and just assume what might be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Id should be an integer, not a string.

```
parser.add_argument('--id', type=int)
```

> By default, `ArgumentParser` objects read command-line arguments in as
>   simple strings. However, quite often the command-line string should
>   instead be interpreted as another type, like a `float` or `int`. The `type`
>   keyword argument of `add_argument()` allows any necessary type-checking
>   and type conversions to be performed.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type

Comment: It won't matter in the query whether you use `1` or `'1'`. Django querysets are robust that way.